# PyCharm and virtualenv new project

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have a problem with PyCharm and virtualenv

When starting a new project, the location is automatically placed in an already started project, and even if I change the location when typing the project name, it automatically returns to the mentioned location project.

Comment: Not 100% clear what you're saying the problem is.  Virtual environments are project-specific. Are you following the PyCharm [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.